# Convolution, confusion

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the density $f_Z(u)$ where $X \in U(0,1)$, $Y \in U(0,\alpha)$ and $Z = X + Y$. I want to use the convolution formula $$f_Z(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(v) f_Y(u-v) dv. $$

I've been looking online for help, and I have found some answers/suggested solutions, but I don't understand them. For example, it states that in the case where $\alpha < 1$, we have $$\int_{v=0}^u f_X(v)f_Y(u-v)dv. $$ In that same example, they had used $V = X$ as an auxiliary variable, so that the above could also be written as $$\int_{x=0}^u f_X(x)f_Y(u-x)dx. $$

Since $X \in U(0,1)$, we should have $0 < x < 1$, and since we have an intergral $$\int (\cdot) \hspace{1mm} dx, $$ shouldn't the boundaries of the integral simply be $0$ and $1$, no matter whether $\alpha$ is smaller than $1$ or not?

I must be very confused about something regarding convolutions, so I'm hoping that someone can help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recall the densities of $X$ and $Y$ first:
\begin{align}
f_X(x)=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x), \ \ \ \ \ f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\alpha)}(y)
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{1}_A(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

Let $z\in (0,1+\alpha)$. So you seem to know that $f_Z(z)$ is given by:
\begin{align}
f_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb{R} f_X(t)f_Y(z-t)\,dt
\end{align}
But both $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are zero most of the time. Where aren't they zero? We  check $f_X$ and $f_Y$ one by one. We start with $f_X(t)$; it is nonzero when $0<t<1$. We have $f_Y(z-t)$ is nonzero when $0<z-t<\alpha$. That means $t<z$ and $z-\alpha<t$. We want to satisfy all these inequality at once. So that means $\max\{z-\alpha,0\}<t<\min\{1,z\}$. Hence:
\begin{align}
f_Z(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_X(t)f_Y(z-t)\,dt=\int^{\min\{1,z\}}_{\max\{z-\alpha,0\}}\frac{1}{\alpha}\,dt=\frac{\min\{1,z\}- \max\{z-\alpha,0\}}{\alpha}
\end{align}
To come back to your question, do the bounds should be from $0$ to $1$? No.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful for me regarding how to approach the bounds. I'm wondering if you know how to complete it at this point? I thought I would add the cases (so e.g. $(1-(z-\alpha))/\alpha + (1-0)/\alpha + \dots $) but I seem to end up with the wrong answer when doing so.

Comment: The density I have written is the density you are looking for. Of course if $z\in (0,1+\alpha)$. Do you want to get rid of the min and max?

Comment: To me it would make sense to state the density the way you stated it. But in the book they hint that there are two cases, $\alpha \geq 1$ and $\alpha < 1$, which makes me think that perhaps they want the answer written in another way (without min and max, I suppose). But I don't have the solution for it, so I can't check for sure what answer they are expecting.

Comment: By splitting cases for $z$ you can write it without min and max. Then you have $f_Z(z)$ is this for $z$ in somewhere and $f_Z(z)$ is that for $z$ in somewhere else, etc etc. You know what I mean? I don't know why they would split cases for $\alpha$.

Comment: For $z < 1$, we would have $\min\{1,z\} = z$, but we wouldn't know what $\max\{z-\alpha, 0\}$ is, since that depends on $\alpha$, no?

Comment: Yes it depends on $\alpha$ but you can say what it is in terms of $\alpha$ it is $0$ if $z<\alpha$ and $z-\alpha$ if $z\geq \alpha$.